# Getting values for time periods

Tags: python, algorithm, datetime, python-3.x

I'm writing a program in Python3 and one of the functions that I need is to calculate a value by reference to two datetime values, per the below.

Imagine that the day is divided into 8 three-hour chunks, always starting at 0000 UTC. Each one of those chunks will have a value, x, that will vary from chunk to chunk but will not vary within the chunk itself.

I need to pass the function a starting datetime object and an ending datetime object and for the function to return a value which is the product of x and the number of minutes in that chunk between the start datetime object and the end datetime object.

So for example, if the start time was 0100 UTC and the end time was 0200 UTC and the x value for the 0000 UTC to 0300 UTC chunk was 20 then that is easy, the value is 60 * 20 = 1200.

If the start time was 0100 UTC and the end time was 0400 UTC and the x value for the 0000 UTC to 0300 UTC chunk was 20 and the x value for the 0300 UTC to 0600 UTC chunk was 30, then the sum would be (20 * 120) + (60 * 30) = 4200

The start time and end time could straddle multiple chunks and even multiple days.

What I am proposing to do is set up a "day_list" of dictionaries where each dictionary is {"startchunk_time": #(e.g. 0000 UTC), "endchunk_time": #(e.g. 0300 UTC), "x": value}. Then the pseudocode would be:

```
def find_value(start_time, end_time):
    test_time = start_time
    while test_time < end_time:
        for item in day_list:
            if test_time > itemstartchunk_time and test_time < endchunk_time:
                #code to add the current x value and increase the test_time by one minute
```

This therefore involves iterating over the entire "day_list" each time, even though the relevant value has been found and the next one will usually be in the same chunk.

My questions are: (i) is there a way of breaking out of the for loop once the value has been found; and (ii) is there a more efficient way of doing this generally?

Comment: (i) is there a way of breaking out of the for loop once the value has been found.... break works fine

(ii) is there a more efficient way of doing this generally?
time delta will give you a timespan for start end times. then divide by the "chunks" would be possible?(or are chunk values not fixed?)

Comment: Thanks but the x value for each chunk varies as between chunks so think that that is not possible.

Comment: So the calculation is minutes * x, x being a chunk of a 24 hour period? I think this could be greatly simplified for long ranges by calculating the chunk up to the end of the first x period and down to the x before the ending date, then simply multiplication and adding the two previous calculations

Comment: are there `8` `x` values in total or the same slot on different days  may have different `x` values?

Comment: Are you including minutes and seconds as part of the calculation or dealing with whole hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task is essentially to find the definite integral over `[a, b]` interval for a piecewise constant function `f(t)`. Therefore the corresponding indefinite integral `F(t)` is a piecewise linear function with the same transition points. From [calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus):

[image: $$\int_a^b f(t) \,dt = F(b) - F(a)$$]

Let's `t[i]` be the start time (transition point) of the `i`-th piece and `f[i]` be the corresponding value. To find the accumulative value for a given time period, you need only to find `F(a)` and `F(b)`. `F[i]` values in the transition points you could calculate in advance. And therefore if `i` is known then the operation is `O(1)` in time.

If `t[i]` times are sorted then you could find  `i` for any given input time `s` in `O(log n)` time using the binary search (`bisect` module). If all slots have the same duration e.g., 3 hours then you could find `i` analytically (in O(1) time):

```
assert s >= t[0]
i = (s - t[0]) // timedelta(hours=3)
```

Assumptions:

- the value for the same time slot e.g., `03..06` may be different on different days
- input time periods such as `[a, b)` are not ordered and they are not equispaced.

Here's code example that computes `find_value()` in constant time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

slot_size = timedelta(hours=3)
slot_size_minutes = slot_size // timedelta(minutes=1)
f = [20, 30] # x values from the question
min_time = datetime(2015, 9, 29) # the time corresponding to f[0]
max_time = min_time + slot_size * len(f)

# compute F[i]
F = [0] * (len(f) + 1)
for i in range(len(f)):
    F[i+1] = F[i] + slot_size_minutes * f[i]

def find_value(start_time, end_time):
    return indefinite_integral(end_time) - indefinite_integral(start_time)

def indefinite_integral(t):
    if min_time <= t <= max_time:
        i = (t - min_time) // slot_size
        t_i = min_time + i * slot_size # i-th transition point
        minutes_in_ith_slot = (t - t_i) // timedelta(minutes=1)  # complete minutes
        return F[i] + f[i] * minutes_in_ith_slot if i < len(f) else F[i]
    else:
        raise ValueError('%r is not in [%s, %s] time range' % (
                         t, min_time, max_time))
```

Example usage:

```
def tt(hhmm):
    hour, minute = divmod(int(hhmm), 100)
    return min_time.replace(hour=hour, minute=minute)

assert find_value(tt("0100"), tt("0200")) == 1200
assert find_value(tt("0100"), tt("0400")) == 4200
```

Answer (score -1):

There's absolutely a way to do this! If there is a will there is a way ;) You're using Python after all.  For loops are simply conditional statements(ie. `if`, `elif`, `else`), so add an `else` statement (the "else" is executed only if the loop terminates normally).  Here is an example of what to do:

```
ctr = 1
while True:
    print "CTR: {0}".format(ctr)
    for x in xrange(10):
        print '\t{0}'.format(x)
        if x == 5:
            print "break FOR loop"
            break
    else:
        print "The FOR loop has completed and no break was hit."
        # do something when a breakpoint hasn't been hit
        break       # break WHILE loop

    print "Break was hit in the FOR loop. Kill the WHILE loop"
    # do something when the FOR loop breaks
    break       # break WHILE loop
```

This may be a bit confusing, but it should run and give you an idea of what to do.  Run it as is, then try commenting out:

```
if x == 5:
    print "break FOR loop"
    break
```

and run the code again and see what happens.  Good luck

Comment: I believe that you have the for-else semantics reversed.  The "else" is executed only if the loop terminates normally.  A "break" will abort the loop and skip the "else".  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: I did initially get it wrong, but I corrected it well before you commented and down voted ;).  But I do like your explanation more than mine so I will change my answer a bit.

Comment: Sorry; the update didn't appear for me for long enough.  Down-vote flipped.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I agree that it's ugly.  For some reason it seemed a lot simpler in my head.  It's quick and dirty for sure.